# Check if a specific charatcer of a string is numeric or alphabetic (python)

Tags: python, string, if-statement

For example, I want a user to input the postal code. However, it has restrictions, such as the length of the postal code has to be 5; first, third, and fifth characters should be digits, while others must be letters. Otherwise, the program should display an error. I guess that I need to write a condition, but I haven't come up with the code, which will check if a specific character of the string is either numeric or alphabetic.

Comment: Looks like a job for regular expressions

Comment: you could use a `try:except` block and convert each character to an int. Alternatively `import string` and then use `string.ascii_lowercase` for example. For SStackOverflow, you should also give the problem a try yourself, and explain where your approach is failing so people can help you, rather than expecting them to do it for you.

Comment: Try regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions here:

```py
postcode = "1A2B3"
if re.search(r'^\d[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z]\d$', postcode):
    print("postal code is valid")
```

The regex use above says to:

```
^             from the start of the postal code
    \d        match a digit
    [A-Za-z]  match a letter
    \d        match a digit
    [A-Za-z]  match a letter
    \d        match a digit
$             end of the postal code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the postcode in a list of characters and use the isnumeric() and isalpha() to check the type for each character in their specific locations of your string-postcode.

```
postal_code = '1A2B3'


def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]

def postal_code_checker(postal_code):

    # check the length of the post_code
    if len(postal_code) != 5:
        return False
    
    #split the postal code  ['1', 'A', '2', 'B', '3']
    char_list = split(postal_code)
    
    #check the type for the specific position
    if char_list[1].isnumeric() or char_list[3].isnumeric():        
        return False

    if char_list[0].isalpha() or char_list[2].isalpha() or char_list[4].isalpha() :        
        return False
    
    #if all is OK return True
    return True


if postal_code_checker(postal_code):
    print('no error')
else:
    print('There was an error')
```